# JsonPath, how to get the records' ids with the minimal value of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, jmeter, jsonpath

I have the following json data:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ticket": "249 [DH-249]",
      "id": 249,
      "priority": 3,
      "title": "kUYWr7gWGH",
      "queue": {
        "title": "Django Helpdesk",
        "id": 1
      },
      "status": "Open",
      "created": "4\u00a0hours ago",
      "due_date": "13\u00a0hours ago",
      "assigned_to": "uUAKA3ZA 2rg8oS9X",
      "submitter": "ke89t9hy@gmail.com",
      "row_class": "",
      "time_spent": "",
      "kbitem": ""
    },
    {
      "ticket": "250 [DH-250]",
      "id": 250,
      "priority": 3,
      "title": "3kEpyPXp4",
      "queue": {
        "title": "Django Helpdesk",
        "id": 1
      },
      "status": "Open",
      "created": "4\u00a0hours ago",
      "due_date": "13\u00a0hours ago",
      "assigned_to": "None",
      "submitter": "cqgZHF7a@gmail.com",
      "row_class": "",
      "time_spent": "",
      "kbitem": ""
    }
  ],
  "recordsFiltered": 195,
  "recordsTotal": 195,
  "draw": 1
}
```

How can i get an array of IDs where the priority is equal to minimal? For example, if the minimal priority is 3 in the data, I need to get id=249, id=250 (there's more data usually)

I have tried using the JsonPath expression gpt gave me: $.data[?(@.priority == $.data[*].priority.min())].id but it does not work

Comment: your question shows javascript, but what JSON Path implementation are you using?

Comment: i use JSONPath 0.5.0

Comment: I'm trying to find the documentation so I can help. There are a lot of "jsonpath" packages. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get it using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) as current implementation doesn't allow evaluating `min()` function properly.

You can switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code to parse the response and extract all `id` attributes of the minimum priority:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data

def minPriority = data.min { it.priority }.priority

def ids = data.findAll(element -> element.priority == minPriority).id

if (ids.size() == 1) {
    vars.put('id', ids.get(0) as String)
} else {
    ids.eachWithIndex { id, index ->
        vars.put('id_' + (index + 1), id as String)
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)